# \wideparen in AMS class

Tags: symbols, accents, amsbook

I need a `\wideparen` symbol in a book prepared with `amsbook` class. I know about a few packages providing this command but...

- `ymath` does not work with current version of AMS classes
- `MnSymbol, mathabx, fourier` - all substitute the default math font and this is not what I need (and what the publisher would allow). I need to keep the standard fonts for everything else, but only add this single symbol.

Any ideas how to do that ?

Comment: By `ymath` do you mean `yhmath`? That package works fine with `amsbook` for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, pdflatex goes into an infinite loop after I add yhmath to the package list. I didn't try to find what is the source of the problem, however some comments I spotted on internet suggested an incompatibility between yhmath and AMS classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's a not-so-little test file that will illustrate the inclusion of a wide paren (and also a wide check) from the `mathx` font using `amsart`.  since `amsbook` is a sibling of `amsart`, it will work there too.  (this is one of the ams internal "how to" files; i didn't edit it for conciseness.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\nofiles
\usepackage{verbatim}

%% code from mathabx.sty and mathabx.dcl
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widecheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wideparen}{0}{mathx}{"75}

\def\cs#1{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}

\begin{document}

A wide check should match a wide hat, but inverted.  Observe that
the forms provided have a maximum width.  Some other wide accents
in \verb|mathx| aren't available otherwise.
\begin{align*}
\cs{widehat}:\quad & \widehat{A}\quad\widehat{AB}\quad
   \widehat{ABC}\quad\widehat{ABCD}\quad\widehat{ABCDE}\\
\cs{widecheck}:\quad & \widecheck{A}\quad\widecheck{AB}\quad
   \widecheck{ABC}\quad\widecheck{ABCD}\quad\widecheck{ABCDE}\\
\cs{wideparen}:\quad & \wideparen{A}\quad\wideparen{AB}\quad
   \wideparen{ABC}\quad\wideparen{ABCD}\quad\wideparen{ABCDE}
\end{align*}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\verbatiminput{\jobname.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works. Yhank you.